# Text to Speech conversion in iPhone using Nuance SDK: Generate .wav file

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am converting text to speech using Nuance SDK and it works fine.
I want to mail the the output to the user as a file, "voice.wav" for example.
Being new to this field, I'm not sure, does this text to speech process create an output file?

I don't see an output file, does it exist?
Can I make it generate one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the SDKs/libraries don't expose access to the raw audio data. This is done in an effort to guarantee the optimal audio subsystem as well as simplifying the process of speech-enabling apps.

Depending on the plan you're enrolled in, you may be able to use the HTTP service, which means you will have to construct your own audio layer. That said, this is your best bet for getting access to the audio data if you *need* it.